# Trying to edit information in File using sed

Tags: shell, sed

i have this code below to update information in a file but i only wish for 1 of the many duplicates to be edited. i only wish for Weapon X's field Stan Lee to be edited but when i ran the code it edited all of the Different field's Stan Lee. 
e.g

```
$ cat BookDB.txt
Weapon X:Stan Lee
Gambit:Stan Lee
Avengers:Stan Lee
```

Code:

```
 function update_author
 {
echo "Title: "
read title_upa
echo "Author: "
read author_upa
grep -iqs "$title_upa:$author_upa:" BookDB.txt && echo "Book Found"
echo "New Author: "
read author_upar
sed  -i s/"$author_upa"/"$author_upar"/ BookDB.txt || tee BookDB.txt && echo "Book Author has been updated sucessfully!"
}
```

Comment: sed is line-oriented. If you want to limit the lines it operates on you need to limit where the patterns are applied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw a similar question to this so here is my solution , change the sed line by getting title and author together before switching the author

```
  sed -i "/^$title:$author:/ s/$author/$author_new/" BookDB.txt
```

Comment: it looks like you have a good understanding with the OP. 7 answers in 30 minutes, all of them accepted within seconds :)

Comment: It just happens that i happen to be doing codes similar to this, so i just gave my answer and it was accepted

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -i "/^$title_upa:/ s/$author_upa/$author_upar/" BookDB.txt
```

The leading regex limits the replacement.

If the user types a value with a `/` character, this will break, so you should escape them:

```
sed -i "/^${title_upa//\//\\/}:/ s/${author_upa//\//\\/}/${author_upar//\//\\/}/" BookDB.txt
```

That's looking a little ridiculous. Let's try a different tool:

```
tmp=$(mktemp)
awk -F: -v OFS=: -v title="$title_upa" -v author="$author_upa" -v new="$author_upar" '
    $1 == title && $2 == author {$2 = new}
    {print}
' BookDB.txt > "$tmp" && mv "$tmp" BookDB.txt
```